# use bash to combine values of the same name

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Input file:

```
AAA 2 3 4 5 
BBB 3 4 5 
AAA 23 21 34
BBB 4 5 62
```

I want the output to be:

```
AAA 2 3 4 5 23 21 34
BBB 3 4 5 4 5 62
```

I feel that I should use `awk` and `sed` but not sure how to realize it. Does anyone have any good ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sort -sk1,1 file | sed ':a;$!N;s/^\([^ ]* \)\(.*\)\n\1/\1\2/;ta;P;D'
AAA 2 3 4 5 23 21 34
BBB 3 4 5 4 5 62
```

or gnu awk;

```
 awk '{if($1 in a){line=$0;sub(/[^ ]* /,"",line);a[$1]=a[$1]line;next};a[$1]=$0}END{n=asort(a);for(i=1;i<=n;i++)print a[i]}' file
AAA 2 3 4 5 23 21 34
BBB 3 4 5 4 5 62
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an awk 1 liner to solve above problem:

```
awk '{line=$2;for(i=3; i<=NF; i++) line=line " " $i; arr[$1]=arr[$1] " " line} END{for (val in arr) print val, arr[val]}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bash version 4's associative arrays

```
$ declare -A vals
$ while read key nums; do vals[$key]+="$nums "; done < filename
$ for key in "${!vals[@]}"; do printf "%s %s\n" "$key" "${vals[$key]}"; done
AAA 2 3 4 5 23 21 34
BBB 3 4 5 4 5 62
```